# input function requirement for train_in_memory

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/boosted_trees_model_understanding

To train an estimator with train_in_memory=false, we use input function

```
 def make_input_fn(X, y, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
  def input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X.to_dict(orient='list'), y))
    if shuffle:
      dataset = dataset.shuffle(NUM_EXAMPLES)
    # For training, cycle thru dataset as many times as need (n_epochs=None).
    dataset = (dataset
      .repeat(n_epochs)
      .batch(NUM_EXAMPLES))
    return dataset
  return input_fn
```

To do so with train_in_memory=true, we use input function

```
def make_inmemory_train_input_fn(X, y):
  y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=1)
  def input_fn():
    return dict(X), y
  return input_fn
```

Why are the two functions so different?

I want to make it similar to `make_input_fn` and tried the following code

```
def make_inmemory_train_input_fn(X, y):
    # y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=1)

    def input_fn():
        return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(X), y))
        # return dict(X), y

    return input_fn
```

It throws error

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for 'boosted_trees/strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.

I totally have no idea how to read it.

I read the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BoostedTreesClassifier

| train_in_memorytrain_in_memory | bool, when true, it assumes the dataset is in memory, i.e., input_fn should return the entire dataset as a single batch, n_batches_per_layer should be set as 1, num_worker_replicas should be 1, and num_ps_replicas should be 0 in tf.Estimator.RunConfig. |
| --- | --- |

What changes do I need to make `from_tensor_slices` work in `make_inmemory_train_input_fn`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the main difference between two input functions is that in-memory will return a dict of numpy array while non-in-memory will return a dict of tensors for `tf.dataset` API to consume. Besides, the former will not need to batch the in memory dataset.
I don't know how to create a `tf.dataset` from slices which will make in-memory computation work. But I tried to pass batch `tf.dataset` within input method and I got "Initialization error". So my guess is that in-memory method doesn't take `tf.dataset` object but numpy slices directly.